# How do I configure my package.json file to read from an env var set in my OS?

Tags: reactjs, proxy, environment-variables, package.json

I'm using React 16.12.0.  I have the following "proxy" configured in my package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:9090",
```

This works great for development, but when I move my site to qa and production, I would like the ability to have my package.json file read from an environment variable of some kind.  How do I write my package.json or configure my app to use a different URL based on the environment, or at least a variable set in my environment?

Comment: Hi Dave, so you are looking to change the proxy when in production mode? From my understanding of the proxy flag for create react is that it is only used in development mode anyway and isn't used in production, more info here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: Hi @ImAnAnt, As a complete react novice, I was looking for a way to configure my app such taht in dev, my requests go to my local server (e.g. http://localhost:9090) but in other environments (e.g. prod), I can make the value of the proxy equal to some other domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

> Keep in mind that proxy only has effect in development (with npm start), and it is up to you to ensure that URLs like /api/todos point to the right thing in production.

As an alternative, you can use environment variables instead: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

You should create `.env.development` and `.env.production` files at the root of your project:

```
# .env.development

REACT_APP_PROXY=http://localhost:9090
```

```
# .env.production
REACT_APP_PROXY=<some other domain>
```

And consume it on the react app:

```js
// anywhere in the react app
const REACT_APP_PROXY = process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY
```

Answer (score 0):

The `proxy` value in `package.json` is static and there is no possible way to retrieve its value from the environment variables. So just use the dynamic way for the proxy registration like described here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually
It will allow you to retrieve any environment variable with the syntax `process.env.SOME_NAME`

Example:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
      target: process.env.BACKEND_URL,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

Now I have answered your primary question, I think this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). When running a react application on a remote environment, there should be a reverse proxy (e.g: Nginx, Apache, ...) in charge of redirecting frontend requests (assets and routes) on the statically served react files, and the backend requests on the backend.
The rule to implement is the following:

- If the incoming requests corresponds to a predefined pattern (e.g: `/api/...`), forward to the internal URL of the backend
- Else, if the request corresponds to a file from react's build, serve it
- Else, assert it's a route, then serve `index.html`

The react's web server should be used on development machines only. It provides real-time compilation and live reload, which is of no use on a production environment, and it's probably not tested against security vulnerabilities. It's still not a bad idea to load the backend's URL from environment variables, as it allows your code base to remain the same for every developer working on your project.

Comment: Hi @GuerricP, thx for this.  What is the name/path of the file that begins with "const proxy = require ..."?

Comment: It's `src/setupProxy.js` (from the doc)

Comment: I assume I should remove the "proxy" configuration I added to my package.json file.  So I did that.  Then I ran the "npm install http-proxy-middleware --save" from your link and created the file in the place you suggested.  However, now running "npm start" results in a "proxy is not a function" error.

Comment: Oh sorry there was a change, the official doc is not up to date, I'm editing my answer